# How Can I position this image horizontally in the centre of it's dynamic parent

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

The page I'm working on has a responsive view.

Products are listed on the page and the product listing scales with the page width.

I want to position the product image in the centre of it's container so that the image takes up the width and size of it's container AND is always centred with the image centre in the centre of `.product`

```
<div class='product'>
  <div class="image_wrapper">
    <a href="/products/1">
      <img scr="http://awesome.image.com/1.jpg">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

since the page is responsive, the content width and height are variable

Can anybody advise?

#### Update

I've created this fiddle to better explain the problem:
As the screen size gets smaller, the image should remain positioned in the centre, with the tower staying centred. The black shading on the edges should slip out of view if the image is wider than it's container

http://jsfiddle.net/gavinmorrice/aUL29/

Comment: Did you wish this to be a background image or foreground?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution my friend :)

```
.product {
    width: auto;
    margin: auto;
}
#image_wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    background-image:url("http://drinkdeals-1-asia.s3.amazonaws.com/development/venues/9a6f8955a3ab7670217425cb50c171ea/wide_venue.jpg");
    height:300px;
    background-position:center; 
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Change your CSS to the above and then remove the image tag from your HTML and CSS :)

Comment: Thanks - this doesn't achieve the effect I'm looking for though :( I've updated my question

Comment: thankyou - that's very close to what I'd achieved. The problem is the image is not positioned in the centre, it's still anchoring to the left.

Comment: What do you mean that is anchoring to the left sorry - Can you provide a screen shot?

Comment: Do you mean that the left hand side has a larger shadow compared to the right hand side?

Comment: Thankyou - your solution worked. I wasn't implementing it correctly

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using

```
.image_wrapper img{
min-width:100%;
}
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Here is example: [http://jsfiddle.net/9X6zD/2/][x]

Parent must have position:relative, and element margin:auto; and display: block;

[demo][1]

Answer (score 0):

you `image_wrapper` div has to get the css as follows:

```
.image-wrapper {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
```

the `img` element has to get following code and it will be rendered completly in the middle

```
img {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Also in this [Blogpost](http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/) you will find further information about centering elements horizontal and vertical.

Comment: Thanks - this doesn't achieve the effect I'm looking for though :( I've updated my question